# how to get stored options from `this.prompt` inside yeoman context?

Tags: javascript, yeoman, scaffolding, yeoman-generator

Basically, yeoman force you to ask everything you need from developer. Although, it’s a good thing, that you can store something and in future runs these things will be autocompleted for developer. The point is that I want to not ask developer if he already answered on that questions.

here is example of basic yeoman generator (`name` will be saved and autocompleted later):

```
var yeoman = require('yeoman-generator');

module.exports = yeoman.generators.Base.extend({
  init: function () {
    var cb = this.async();

    this.prompt([{
      name: 'name',
      message: 'your name:',
      store: true,
    }, {
      name: 'moduleName',
      message: 'module name:'
    }], function (props) {
      console.log(
        props.name,      // developer’s name
        props.moduleName // module’s name
      )
    }.bind(this));
  },
}
});
```

The question is how to get stored options from `this.prompt` inside yeoman context to do smth like this:

```
this.prompt([!this.name.stored && {
  name: 'name', // so after first run this will never be asked again
  message: 'your name:',
  store: true,
}, {
  name: 'moduleName',
  message: 'module name:'
}], function (props) {
  console.log(
    props.name,      // developer’s name
    props.moduleName // module’s name
  )
}.bind(this));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no public way to access the stored previous prompt answers.

If you want to cache some data and access it later, then use the [storage functionality](http://yeoman.io/authoring/storage.html) (`this.config`)

FWIW, the prompt cache is stored into the private [`this._globalConfig`](https://github.com/yeoman/generator/blob/master/lib/base.js#L155). I'm adding this detail for completeness, you probably shouldn't use it.

Answer (score 1):

You can user default's value as function, where first argument is prev stored answers:

```
const answers = await this.prompt([
  {
    type: 'input',
    name: 'projectName',
    message: 'Your project id',
    default: this.appname,
    store: true
  },
  {
    type: 'input',
    name: 'projectTitle',
    message: 'Your project title',
    default: ({ projectName }) => projectName
  },
])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a *config.js* that will store and read the information in the users home directory as a *config.json* file and later the app can read this file that can be used as a default.

```json
{
    name: 'authorName',
    message: 'What\'s your name?',
    'default': self.defaultAuthorName
}
```

Check out https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-yo-wordpress where the developer makes use of a *config.js* file.

Comment: it feels like a hach, because storage functionality is doing the same